# Add an OS X Server Account Fails With No Clear Error

Tags: macos, osx-server, smb

I have basically pure Mac Networks, one production and one test. Both are running 10.9.4 and the servers have the latest Server.app.

I used to be able to configure users' access to services by using Internet Accounts --> Add Other Account --> Add an OS X Server Account. But recently this seems to have stopped working, with status icons next to the services the user wants connected just spinning indefinitely. I switched and rebuilt a clean test server/workstation and ended up with the same behavior so it doesn't appear restricted to a set workstation or server. I had thought Profile Manager might have been the source of the problem, but the test network does not have profile manager configured.

Configuration-wise, the only thing I've changed recently is the protocol providing users' home directories from AFP to SMB.

After the spinning occurs for a couple of minutes, all heck breaks loose in the system log and SMB connection to the user's home directory is lost, thus requiring a restart. The log entries are really a mess but they seem to be addressing the lost connection. Google hasn't been much help with this situation either.

Edit: I should have included, if I add and Addressbook account separately, I am seeing troubles with the user being able to actually pull down contacts. And if I can figure out how to get a valid connection, I'm seeing two contact accounts showing up in the list and one is empty (appears to be read only as I cannot add contacts to that).

I'm curious if anyone else has seen this behavior, and if so what OS/Server versions are you using? If this method of configuring services works for you, will you share some details of your set up, to include SMB/AFP?

Thanks.